# How can I remove the ugly applet icon background? [Lubuntu]

Tags: lubuntu, icons, applet

I've recently changed the icons on my Lubuntu machine, but puzzlingly, the panel applets for volume control and wifi have a bizarre grey background which I cannot seem to remove. This isn't happening on any of my other panel icons.

Is there anyway to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just attached the output

Comment: Are the Papirus-Dark and ThinIce themes from the standard repos or did you get them from elsewhere?

Comment: I can't find ThinIce in the repos. The versions elsewhere are pretty old.

Comment: Icons are a git hub package, theme I have no idea, im using the Nightmare Openbox theme

Comment: I added a bit about ThinIce (and some other themes) being unsuitable for general use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your exact set-up, but I can reproduce the background appearing behind certain icons.

It appears that the issue lies with the choice of GTK theme. <s>While I don't have ThinIce installed, I have others.</s> I used Lubuntu's *Customize Look and Feel* application to change GTK themes.

In the animation below, you can see

- a white background with "Materia-light"
- a dark background with "Materia" and
- no background with "Lubuntu-default"

[image: Animation showing effect of changing GTK themes]

In addition to Lubuntu-dark, other suitable themes include Greybird and Numix which you can install using `sudo apt install shimmer-themes`.

---

Notes:

1. I prefer to use themes in the repositories because they're more likely to be suitable for the GTK version of the OS. If you want to use themes from elsewhere, ensure they're recent and support your GTK version (which you can check using `apt policy libgtk-3.0`.)
2. *ThinIce* and some other themes in `/usr/share/themes` contain only a *gtk-2.0* folder while some other themes such as *Emacs* and *Default* contain a *gtk-3.0* folder as well but aren't suitable for general use.

Comment: Perfect! I neglected to get widget themes! Thanks